# Python if attribute is not found statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

For now my script won't run because some of the items in my list does not contain the attribute `img`.

```
for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
```

How can I write an `if-statement` in which my script will return a default value if the attribute `img` does not exist and keep running the script for the items that have the attribute `img`.

Comment: Need more information to answer your question. Usually `try/except` is for this type of thing.

Comment: you can check for img attribute existence in if condition first and then do something on it ...

Comment: What is `container`? If you've got lxml.objectify'd/soup objects or similar - there's ways to query them such that you only get objects with those attributes to start with...

Comment: its a soup object. Just started learning about it, did it know that. Assumed if statement was the only way around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try/except` will do the thing

```
for container in containers:
    try:
        brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
    except AttributeError:
        brand = 'default value'
```